# How to show manipulated html using jquery in modal's bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

This is my general modal's bootstrap :

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="myModal">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
            <h2>Konfirmasi Perubahan Status Request</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="controls" id="chekboxes">               
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label class="control-label">Kind Of Complaint :</label></td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <div class="controls" id="chekboxes">
                                        <label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="request[]" id="Login"    value="Login"     /> Login </label>
                                        <label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="request[]" id="Printer"  value="Printer"   /> Printer </label>
                                        <label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="request[]" id="Monitor"  value="Monitor"   /> Monitor</label>
                                        <label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="request[]" id="Computer" value="Computer"  /> Computer</label>
                                        <label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="request[]" id="Network"  value="Network"   /> Network</label>
                                        <label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="request[]" id="Other"    value="Lain-lain" /> Other</label> 
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top"><label class="control-label">Description :</label></td>
                            <td><div class="control-group ">
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <textarea class="cleditor" name="keluhan" id="modalkeluhan" rows="3"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>                    
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a href="#" id="btn-footer" class="btn btn-danger">Ya</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Tidak</a>   
        </div>

    </div>
```

In this modal, I want to send some data using ajax. But why its not sent to modal? 
I was checked the ajax in firebug, and it is success.
This is the ajax :

```
 $(".btn-info").click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var $this = $(this);
     var idStr = $this.attr("req_id");
     var idText = idStr.split("/").pop();
     console.log(idText);

      $.ajax({
      url: '<?php echo base_url() . 'control_closing/getDetailOfRequest/' ?>',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {id: idText},
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(obj) {
        console.log(obj); // output == > Object { jenis_request="Login, Printer, Monitor", keluhan="Test"}
        console.log(obj.jenis_request); // output ==> Login, Printer, Monitor
        console.log(obj.keluhan); // output ==> Test

       var jr = obj.jenis_request.split(",")

       for (var j in jr) {
          $('input[type=checkbox][value=' + jr[j] + ']').prop('checked=checked', true);
       }

       $('#modalkeluhan').val(obj.keluhan);
       $('#myModal').modal('show');
       }
    });
```

How to show manipulated html using jquery in modal's bootstrap ?

This is the html to executed this ajax :

```
<td  class="center">
   <a class="btn btn-info" id="btn-edit" name="edit" req_id="<?php echo $data['kode_kantor'] . '/' . $data['kode_departement'] . '/' . date('m', strtotime($data['bulan'])) . '/' . $data['id_request']; ?>">
      <i class="halflings-icon white edit"></i>
    </a>

    <a class="btn btn-success" >
       <i class="halflings-icon white print" id="print"></i>
    </a>         
 </td>
```

Comment: do u have any console errors..??

Comment: this is console.log :

{"jenis_request":"Login, Printer, Monitor","keluhan":"Test"}

Login

Printer

Monitor

Test

Comment: other than the response do u have any errors..??

Comment: @FadlyDzil a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) will be great

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Fadly_Dzil_Massere/k6x0oj84/

Comment: Check this mate http://jsfiddle.net/jptgoshx/